# Llevar contador en python

Tags: python, contador

Buen dia.

Estoy haciendo un programa sencillo que me lleve la suma de cada iteracion de vehiculos, y al final me muestra la cantidad total de los mismos.
El codigo que hize es el siguiente:

```
from random import random

nAutos=0
for i in range(3):
aleatorioAuto = random()
if aleatorioAuto > 0 and aleatorioAuto < 0.10:          
    nAutos = 0
elif aleatorioAuto > 0.10 and aleatorioAuto < 0.20:     
    nAutos = 1
    print("Usted ordeno: ", str(nAutos), "Vehiculos")
    nAutos+=1
elif aleatorioAuto > 0.20 and aleatorioAuto < 0.60:      
    nAutos = 2
    print("Usted ordeno: ", str(nAutos), "Vehiculos")
    nAutos+=1
elif aleatorioAuto >0.60 and aleatorioAuto < 0.80:     
    nAutos = 3
    print("Usted ordeno: ", str(nAutos), "Vehiculos")
    nAutos+=1
elif aleatorioAuto > 0.80 and aleatorioAuto < 1:     
    nAutos = 4
    print("Usted ordeno: ", str(nAutos), "Vehiculos")
    nAutos+=1
total=nAutos
print(total)
print("--------------------------Fin del programa---------------------------
")
```

total, solo me muesra la ultima iteracion que obtuvo y le suma 1.
Esta es la salida del programa:

```
Usted ordeno:  2 Vehiculos
Usted ordeno:  2 Vehiculos
Usted ordeno:  3 Vehiculos
4
```

si se genereo ( 2 2 3 vechiculos, el total deberia arrojar 7). ¿Cual es mi error?, espero me puedan ayudar.
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas perdiendo el valor que llevabas por iteración de `nAutos` Si por ejemplo `nAutos` ya valia 2, y vuelves a entrar y cae en el caso que vale 3, estas reemplazando el valor, no lo estás sumando. Edité un poco tu código, creo que te puede funcionar mejor de esta forma.

```
from random import random
nAutos = 0
for i in range(3):
aleatorioAuto = random()
if aleatorioAuto > 0 and aleatorioAuto < 0.10:          
    nAutos += 0
elif aleatorioAuto > 0.10 and aleatorioAuto < 0.20:     
    nAutos += 1
    print("Usted ordeno: 1 Vehiculos")
elif aleatorioAuto > 0.20 and aleatorioAuto < 0.60:      
    nAutos += 2
    print("Usted ordeno: 2 Vehiculos")
elif aleatorioAuto >0.60 and aleatorioAuto < 0.80:     
    nAutos += 3
    print("Usted ordeno: 3 Vehiculos")
elif aleatorioAuto > 0.80 and aleatorioAuto < 1:     
    nAutos += 4
    print("Usted ordeno: 4 Vehiculos")
print("Total de autos pedidos: " + str(nAutos) )
print("--------------------------Fin del programa---------------------------
")
```

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente no estaba sumando las iteraciones anteriore.